# I'm getting Response code:403 in jmeter while running in windows server 2019 but when running in windows 10 it is working

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, http-status-code-403

When i'm running same script in windows 10 it is working fine but when i'm running in windows server 2019 then 403 forbidden error is getting
and while running for staging server it is working fine both windows 10 and windows server 2019

I have tried different authentication and also tried changing the time zone

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it's due to improperly implemented or missing [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start).

In the majority of cases you cannot just replay the recorded script without handling dynamic parameters.

First of all make sure to add HTTP Cookie Manager to your test plan, it might help you to resolve the issue.

In case if this is not sufficient inspect request and response details and look for "suspicious" dynamic values. The easiest option is just recording your test scenario twice and comparing resulting [.jmx scripts](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan). All parameters which are different are a subject to correlation. You will need to:

1. Extract dynamic values from the previous response using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and save them into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
2. Replace recorded hard-coded values with the JMeter Variables from the Step 1

More information: [How to Handle Correlation in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter)